# Clicking on store view redirects to a website

Tags: multistore, store-view

When I choose a particular store view in the configuration page of admin, it redirects to a url instead of staying and showing me the configuration of that store

How can I fix it? I tried to search for url in the files and it was not available so it seems that it is coming from database but I don't know how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was from .htaccess file and I should have editted the redirects

Comment: sure, in 6 hours